# Can you modify the body of an outgoing HTTP request?

Tags: http, security, postman, middleware

I am working on a web app that integrates with Stripe. I have a frontend which calculates a total price which I am sending to a middleware service over HTTP inside the body. I am worried about a security flaw, where someone can intercept the body of my HTTP request I am making to my middleware and change the total price to a lower amount. This would result in them paying less for a product. I've been playing around with Postman but I can only seem to intercept the request to see the data being passed, rather than being able to edit it. Is this even a possibility? If so, how can I guard against it?
Thanks

Comment: This is why you should be using HTTPS instead, to avoid such man-in-the-middle attacks. The client should validate that it is actually talking to the correct middleware before exchanging any sensitive data with it. The encryption will prevent modifications

Answer (score 3):

The main way to guard against this is to *not* let the client pass the price at all.

The client just needs to tell the server which products the client wants to buy. The server uses the product list and quantities to figure out the total price.

And to answer your main question:

Assume that users can fully control every HTTP request, including headers, body, url and method. You cannot trust *any* information inside of it, everything can be altered.